# composer is not removing entry from composer.lock

Tags: composer-php

I've used following command to remove a package using composer.

```
composer remove sjparkinson/static-review
```

Above command removes entry from `composer.json` file but composer.lock file still contains entry for mentioned library in `require` section.

What is the proper way to update `composer.lock` ? Should I update it manually?

Comment: Show result of `composer why sjparkinson/static-review`.

Comment: It says magento/product-community-edition  2.2.4  requires  sjparkinson/static-review (~4.1).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Composer does not removing this package, because it is required by another dependency. So even if you don't require it directly, it is still required by your project, so you cannot remove it. You can use `composer why some-vendor/some-package` command to check what is the reason to keep this package installed:

```
composer why sjparkinson/static-review
```

> magento/product-community-edition 2.2.4 requires sjparkinson/static-review (~4.1)

If you really want to remove this package, you need to remove `magento/product-community-edition` too (and every dependency, which depends on this package).

---

BTW: Editing `composer.lock` manually is really bad idea, you should never do that.

Comment: what if I have this result: `There is no installed package depending on "guzzlehttp/psr7"`? and still it's not removed from `composer.lock`

Comment: @spirit `guzzlehttp/psr7` provides `psr/http-message-implementation`, so I would check if anything requires `psr/http-message-implementation`.